# How to use Serilog in multiple API/Web projects?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog

Here i develop serilog for one project.

**Program.cs**

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Warning("Starting BuildWebHost");

            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSerilog()
            .Build();
}
```

}

**strong text**
**Controller**
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class TestController : Controller
{
    ILogger _logger;

```
public HomeController(ILogger<TestController > logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _logger.LogDebug("TestController instantiated.");
}
```

}

**Question**
1. how can serilog configuration in class library?
2. how to configuration different skin for different project?

Comment: Hi! I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking - can you please include details of what you've tried, and how that hasn't worked? Cheers!

Comment: I have create on sample serilog with MSSQL Sinks..now i want to create custom class library for serilog logging with all the dynamic configuration.